# VS Code highlights the correct Flex Box syntax as an error

Tags: syntax, visual-studio-code

VS Code has started highlighting a number of the old flex box syntax properties (for use in older browsers) as a syntax error,  when this isn't the case (image attached).

Is this something I can correct in the editor itself, or will it have to be done in a future update?

[image]

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove those warnings with these settings:

> // When using a vendor-specific prefix also include the standard
>   property

```
"css.lint.vendorPrefix": "ignore",
"scss.lint.vendorPrefix": "ignore",
"less.lint.vendorPrefix": "ignore",
```

You are getting those warnings because you are not also including the non-prefixed versions like

```
box-align: "center"
```